# Get network name via command-line?

Tags: python, networking

Is there a command-line or Python way for getting the network names that show up in Control Panel -> Network Connection?

"S_____-Guest", "Ir______15"

[image]

"ipconfig /all" and "route print" do not seem to include this info.

Comment: Maybe [this might help](https://superuser.com/a/991484)?

Comment: FYI, networks do not have names, they have addresses. That is simply what your PC on that network calls it. Other devices on the same network can have other "names" for the same network.